# Animate matplotlib's Poly3DCollection

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to animate a matplotlib plot containing a Poly3DCollection.
I'm following the instructions at https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/animation_api.html

I start initializing the faces and the vertices of my surface:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D, art3d
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

def init_faces(N):
    f = []
    for r in range(N-1):
        for c in range(N-1):
            v0 = r*N+c
            f.append([v0, v0+1, v0+N+1, v0+N])
    return np.array(f)    

def init_vert(N):
    v = np.meshgrid(range(N),range(N),[0])
    return np.dstack(v).reshape(-1,3)

def set_amplitude(v,A):
    v[:,2] = A * (np.sin(np.pi*v[:,0]/(N-1)) * np.sin(np.pi*v[:,1]/(N-1)))
    return v


N = 10
f = init_faces(N)
v = init_vert(N)
```

I then initialize the figure

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax    = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1,projection="3d")

pc = art3d.Poly3DCollection(v[f])
#pc.set_animated(True) # Is this required? Why?

ax.add_collection(pc)
```

and the updating functions

```
def init_fig():
    ax.set_xlim([0, N])
    ax.set_ylim([0, N])
    ax.set_zlim([0, 5])
    return pc,

def update_fig(frame):
    A = np.sin(frame)
    new_v = set_amplitude(v,A)
    pc.set_verts(new_v[f])
    return pc,
```

However, when I call the animation, nothing happens

```
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update_fig, frames=np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 128),
                    init_func=init_fig, blit=False, repeat=True)

plt.show()
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can `print(v[:,2].max())` during the animation to find that z is always 0. The reason is that you initialize an integer array

```
v = np.meshgrid(range(N),range(N),[0])
```

and since the sin and cos are always smaller one, they stay 0 when cast to integer.

Initialize a float array instead, e.g. via

```
v = np.meshgrid(range(N),range(N),[0.0])
```

Then it will work as expected.